# data-toggle in a html table tag asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

i was looking through a sample application .
when i was going through the application i saw two attributes for a table tag are
`data-toggle` and `data-target`. 
Can some one help me on this.
why actually they are needed.

Comment: Dear Dineshreddybandi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend you to take a little tour here http://stackoverflow.com/about. Don't forget to upvote good answers and questions and to mark as correct the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`data-` attributes were introduced in HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to allow application-specific data storage. That is, any attribute that starts with `data-` will be considered valid as an HTML attribute, but most browsers will ignore it. It's up to the application to make use of these attributes.

I don't know which project you were analyzing, but it's probably used by a Javascript library to run some rich interface functionality. [I know that Twitter Bootstrap uses it for modal windows](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), so you can see it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Bootstrap defined HTML5 data attribute.

```
data-toggle="modal"
data-toggle="collapse"
data-toggle="dropdown"
data-toggle="tab"
```

Example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not strict to Bootstrap, `data-*` attributes are HTML5 attributes and any library may use its own. I recommend you to edit or remove your answer before you get downvoted.

Comment: agree but bootstrap has define "data-toggle" attribute in their plugins he is asking about this attribute not about "data-"